# html and javascript audio player with django backend

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm  creating a music streaming website for my final year project.Most of my work is done except actually making the audio play and stream with django.I was wondering if i can make an audio player with html5 and js and get django to render it.Can any one point me to the right direction.